# Python Convert a File with CRLF to new ROW in CSV/Excel

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the text file from API output to an excel /CSV file. Text file consists of CRLF \r \n value , which needs to be used as a line break and added as a new row in CSV /Excel file.

Below is the file sample :

b'2020-03-16 00:23:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:24:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:25:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:26:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:27:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:28:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:29:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:30:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:31:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:32:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:33:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:34:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:35:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:36:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:37:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:38:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:39:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:40:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:41:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:42:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:43:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:44:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:45:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:46:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:47:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:48:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:49:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:50:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:51:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:52:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:53:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:54:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:55:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:56:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:57:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:58:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:59:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:00:33,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:01:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:02:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:03:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:04:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:05:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:06:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:07:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:08:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:09:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:10:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:11:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:12:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:13:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00

Comment: did you try anything so far?

Comment: I tried to remove the Escape sequence directly from the text file before converting it to CSV file by using this code . Nevertheless i tired many other options , but none of them doesn't worked.filename = "NameOfFileToBeConverted"
fileContents = open(filename,"r").read()
f = open(filename,"w", newline="\n")
f.write(fileContents)
f.close()

Comment: Why not read into a `pandas.DataFrame` then use the DataFrame's `to_csv()` function to output the file?  Pandas should be smart enough to cope with the Win line endings.

Comment: Tried this code as well, but this prints all the data in a single ROW even with escape sequence , i wanted to be in a new row without escape character.import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv (r'Path where the Text file is stored\File name.txt')
read_file.to_csv (r'Path where the CSV will be saved\File name.csv', index=None)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has the way to handle csv's fine... yes even on windows.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = b'2020-03-16 00:23:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:24:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:25:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16'

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.decode('ascii')))
```

and you can write to a csv file

```
df.to_csv("filename")
```

or to excel (provided that excelwriter is installed)

```
df.to_excel("filename.xls")
```

Comment: Great, this works. However, if we would like to read a entire text file rather than a string, without copying the content of text file to string variable , do we have any option ?

Comment: no, that doesn't work. All contents are pasted in a single row

Comment: Oh I see it.  it has to be a filename or a StringIO.  (can't be a BytesIO)  so it means opening up the file and converting it.  from pathlib import Path df.read_csv(io.StringIO(Path('filename').read_bytes().decode('ascii')))

Comment: I tried like this , but it's still pasting in a single row with Escape sequence.import io
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(Path(sample.txt').read_bytes().decode('ascii')))
df.to_csv("Demo1.csv")